# Selecting a JDBC Driver

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm trying to select a JDBC driver for an application I'm building and I've found lots of drivers, but I can't seem to narrow the selection down to one. The driver I select should have the following features:

1. Free for commercial use
2. Easy to install (eg. single jar file, no drivers to install)
3. Easy to use (well documented)
4. No database server required
5. Multi-user / Network support

What JDBC database drivers would you suggest?

So far I've considered TinySQL and SQLite.

The database is not very large think maybe 10k records.

Comment: Question #1: What database are you targeting?

Comment: Haven't selected one. So I guess I'm asking what database should I use.

Comment: I want to use a JDBC driver so if I change databases the database will have the same interface. Right now I need a database that meets the above requirements.

Comment: Pick your database and the jdbc driver will follow.

Comment: Can I connect to a MySQL database without having a MySQL server application running?

Comment: If you want portability (at the cost of performance), then look at using an ORM to connect to various databases.  JDBC drivers are for specific database vendors, and are tailored -- the SQL isn't guaranteed to work between vendors so you need to research better before going further.

Comment: HSQLDB or Derby if you need embedded.

Comment: The whole point of JDBC is that the API is consistent regardless of which DBMS you use. A database-specific JDBC driver handles the database-specific interface requirements.  In theory, if you change DBMS, you just switch to using the associated JDBC driver with no change to your application.  In practice, this works pretty well so long as you steer clear of DBMS-specific SQL syntax.

Comment: @mjh2007: to connect to mysql, you need mysql server. What you're looking for is so-called 'embedded' database, one that runs within your application. There are few such databases in Java. Popular ones include Derby or H2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JDBC driver depends on the database you want to use. Some free databases include:

- Derby (small, lightweight, comes with Java 1.6)
- MySQL (bigger, lots of features)
- PostgreSQL (bigger, lots of features)

I'm sure there are others.

When you install the database, the documentation will tell you where to get the JDBC driver.

Comment: Derby is only included with JDK, not with JRE. Make sure you bundle it with your application if you use it.

Comment: HSQLDB might also be an option.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have specific requirements, I would have suggested that you use [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/), it is free and very popular. Also, it is very easy to use through JDBC. However, I then saw your comment:

> I want to use a JDBC driver so if I
>   change databases the database will
>   have the same interface. Right now I
>   need a database that meets the above
>   requirements.

The problem is that, as far as I know, JDBC alone isn't that flexible. With JDBC you basically pass strings to and fro the application and the database engine. If you want something that allows you to change the database but doesn't impact the way that your application and database communicate, you should consider and ORM tool like [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/).

Answer (score 1):

The OP asked for 'no database server'. That means that there are two options in common use: Derby and HSQLDB that integrate well into Java.

Comment: or H2, which I would actually recommend over derby and hsqldb.